# Как реализовать в дереве позицию после конца и перед началом?

Tags: c++, дерево, бинарное-дерево, итераторы

Имеется бинарное самобалансирующееся дерево. Как лучше в нем реализовать элементы после конца и перед началом (чтобы потом бегать по дереву с помощью итераторов)?

Был такой вариант: [http://i.imgur.com/iqrWYI3.png](https://i.imgur.com/iqrWYI3.png)
То есть добавить родительский элемент для корня дерева. Тогда в конце обхода я всегда бы приходил туда. Но такой способ не устраивает из-за того, что не будет возможности вернуться на предыдущий элемент. Как только я попаду в эту вершину, то оттуда уже не получится выбраться

Еще думал добавить самому левому листу дочернюю вершину, которая будет элементом перед началом. Аналогично с правым нижним листом. Но из-за постоянных перестроений дерева отказался от этой идеи.

Comment: На скриншоте изобразил указатели на родительский элемент. То есть, самый верхний элемент является родителем сам для себя и для root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто, пусть нулевой указатель означает конечный элемент `end()`:

```
template<typename NodeType, typename DataType = typename NodeType::DataType>
class TreeIterator
{
    NodeType * Current;

public:
    TreeIterator(NodeType * node) : Current(node)
    {}

    TreeIterator & operator = (const TreeIterator & right)
    {
        // ...
    }

    DataType & operator * ()
    {
        if(Current)
        {
           return Current->Data;
        }
        else throw OutOfRange();
    }

    TreeIterator operator ++ (int)
    {
        NodeType * temp = Current;
        Current = nextNode();
        return TreeIterator(temp);
    }

    TreeIterator operator ++ ()
    {
        Current = nextNode();
        return TreeIterator(Current);
    }

    bool operator == (const TreeIterator & right) const
    {
        return Current == right.Current;
    }

private:
    NodeType * nextNode()
    {
        if(Current)
        {
            // переходим к следующему узлу, если доходим до
            // конца возвращаем nullptr
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Ну и собственно функция `end()`:

```
TreeIterator<Node> end() const
{
    return TreeIterator<Node>(nullptr);
}
```